# How to overload assign operator for assigning a object at the time of initialization in c++

Tags: c++, string

i want to overload the assignment operator such that it will be used to assign data at the time of initialization of object

for initializing a string object we can follow the format given below

```
string str = "Hello World !!!";
```

but it will be a error if we define our object in same manner;

for example

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Name{
private:
    string name;
public:
    Name(){}
    Name(string str){
        name=str;
    }
};
int main(){
    Name name="Jack";
}
```

it is showing error like

```
E:\Documents\test.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
E:\Documents\test.cpp|13|error: conversion from 'const char [5]' to non-scalar type 'Name' requested|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

so how to make a class such that it can accept data like string object .

Comment: Why not simply write `Name name("Jack")`? You don't need operator overloading for that.

Comment: `Name name="Jack";` is not an assignation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Name name="Jack";` is initialization, not assignment, so it has nothing to do with assignment operator.

Note that `"Jack"` is not a `std::string`, but a string literal with type `const char[5]`. Then for `Name name="Jack";`, which is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), it needs to be converted to `std::string` and then converted to `Name`. But only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one conversion sequence.

You can add another constructor taking `const char*`,

```
class Name{
    ...
    Name(const char* s) : name(s) {}
};
```

[Implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) from `const char[]` to `const char*` is qualified as standard conversion then the code works fine.

Or change `Name name="Jack";` to `Name name("Jack");`, which is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), `"Jack"` will be converted to `std::string`, and the constructor of `Name` taking `std::string` will be invoked directly to initialize the object.

Or use `Name name = "Jack"s;`, while `"Jack"s` is a [`std::string` literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14) with type `std::string`, then only one conversion (from `std::string` to `Name`) is needed.

Comment: Would be good to clarify that the conversion from `const char[5]` to `const char*` is not a user-defined conversion---the OP doesn't seem to have much background.

Comment: Suggesting `"Jack"s` without another word of explanation is counter productive. The OP's code will fail to build the moment someone tells them to get rid of that awful `using namespace std;`.

Comment: thanks for giving interest here. Actually i am writing the Big-integer class in c++ so i want to make it in such a way that it completely behave like a normal data type.means any user who use my class never feel that it is a user defined data type so in that case initialization with constructor will slightly different from normal approach.so can you tell me any alternate approach possible or not such that we can directly initialize the value as we do with int,float .

Comment: @Sourav For `int` or `float` the issue of `Name name="Jack";` shouldn't apply; could you make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of that to make the trouble more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side of this line (which is not an assignment but an object definition and an initialization):

```
Name name = "Jack";
```

invokes the [fifth string constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) because "Jack" is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const char[]` and not `std::string` which is what your user defined `Name(string str)` constructor expects. To make it of type `std::string` append the `s` literal using the [operator ""s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) which constructs a literal of type `std::string`:

```
Name name = "Jack"s;
```

and compile with C++14 support enabled or add a constructor that accepts `const char*` parameter:

```
Name(const char* str) { 
    name = str;
}
```

Either way you need to include the `<string>` header when working with `std::string` type.